# How can I color text in <p> that it contains in a <div>

Tags: html, css

How to color a text in a `<p>` that it contains in a `<div>` when the user hovers with the mouse.

Suppose  I have this html code:

```
<div id="riga_ristorante_1" >
<div>
  <p>HI</p>
</div>
<div><p>HOME</p></div>
<div><p>DOG</p></div>
</div>
```

I want color the "hi","HOME","DOG" in black when the user go on the `<p>` element, so I use CSS:

```
#riga_ristorante_1:hover > p {
     text-align: center;
     color: black;

}
```

But it doesn't work. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Try `#riga_ristorante_1:hover p { ... }` - or `#riga_ristorante_1 p:hover { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

You are using a [child combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) (a greater than sign: `>`), but the div with the id your selector matches is the **grandparent** of the paragraphs, not the parent.

Use a [descendant combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) (a space: ) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting the paragraph directly after your ID div which in your html you don't have a paragraph tag that is a immediate child of your `riga_ristorante_1`

for more info on `>` selector

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

With your given html you can do

```
#riga_ristorante_1:hover p { ... }
```

or

```
#riga_ristorante_1:hover div > p { ... }
```

or

```
#riga_ristorante_1 div:hover > p { ... }
```

or even

```
#riga_ristorante_1 p:hover { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

css selector will be `riga_ristorante_1:hover > div > p {}`

```css
#riga_ristorante_1:hover > div > p {
     text-align: center;
     color: blue;

}
```

```html
<div id="riga_ristorante_1" >
<div>
  <p>HI</p>
</div>
<div><p>HOME</p></div>
<div><p>DOG</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your `p` as second level in deep, so you can't use `>` as it applies to first level only. Use

```
#riga_ristorante_1:hover p {
     color: red;
}
```

```css
#riga_ristorante_1:hover p {
     color: red;

}
```

```html
<div id="riga_ristorante_1" >
<div>
  <p>HI</p>
</div>
<div><p>HOME</p></div>
<div><p>DOG</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `#riga_ristorante_1  p:hover` just give `toggle` effect

```css
#riga_ristorante_1  p:hover {
     text-align: center;
     color: blue;

}
```

```html
<div id="riga_ristorante_1" >
<div>
  <p>HI</p>
</div>
<div><p>HOME</p></div>
<div><p>DOG</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave the HTML Code but change your css selector to `#riga_ristorante_1  div > p:hover` then set your preferred styles

HTML Code

```html
<div id="riga_ristorante_1" >
  <div><p>HI</p></div>
  <div><p>HOME</p></div>
  <div><p>DOG</p></div>
</div>
```

The css selector should be `#riga_ristorante_1  div > p:hover` so the css will look like below and add more styles if you like like the text-align in the original css code.

CSS Code

```css
#riga_ristorante_1  div > p:hover {
     color: blue;    
}
```